# VLOOKUP or INDEX-MATCH formula for database

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, vlookup

I am currently working on merging 2 databases.  Information has been altered for example purposes.

[image: Spreadsheet of 2 Databases]

In the top spreadsheet, I have all the information that I will be needing.  In the bottom is the database with almost the rest of the information.  In the top I have two identifiers, the full acocunt number and the full card number.  The bottom spreadsheet has peoples information, full account number and a card number that has been masked except for the last four digits.

If I create a VLOOKUP on the last 4 digits of the card number I will run into instances that have the same last 4 digits as well.  If I run a VLOOKUP on the account number I know I will only pull the first instance of a shared account number.  I am trying to get all the data from the bottom database to the top. I am not quite as familiar with INDEX-MATCH formula.  Is it possible to search matching information in two cells and then query the corresponding cell?
I.E.: "if the 4 digit card and account number of database 1 match the 4 digit card and account number of database 2, then name?"

Comment: Check out [multi criteria Index/Match](https://www.deskbright.com/excel/index-match-multiple-criteria/), I think that's what you're looking for.

Comment: I am looking at the article you sent me, thank you, but I am getting a value error when I input the following 

=INDEX($D$17:$D$20,MATCH($I2&$K2,$B$17:$B$20&$C$17:$C$20,0))

Comment: Dang it, just realized I was not putting "CTL+SHIFT+ENTER"

Comment: @BruceWayne - why don't you create an answer? Just a short summary of the technique and the link?

Answer (score 1):

This is a great opportunity to use the `Index/Match` method with multiple criteria.  [This page](https://www.deskbright.com/excel/index-match-multiple-criteria/) does a good job summarizing how, but here's a quick solution for you (that you found too):

`=INDEX($D$17:$D$20,MATCH($I2&$K2,$B$17:$B$20&$C$17:$C$20,0))` 

**Enter with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> as it's an array formula.**

Generally, you would use a normal `Index/Match`, just add lookup and ranges with `&`:

`=Index([range of values you want to return],MATCH([Lookup 1]&[Lookup 2]&...&[Lookup N],[Lookup1 Range]&[Lookup2 Range]&...&[LookupN Range],0))`.

So if you need to add more criteria, just add them to the `Match()`.